# Change Visual Studio Code's title bar icon

Tags: visual-studio-code

[icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg8cd.jpg)
Is it possible to remove this icon or change it to another one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need this but you can install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css), and inject a CSS file to replace the icon.

Here's my CSS file contents in case you need it.

```
.monaco-workbench .part.titlebar .window-appicon > .home-bar-icon-badge,
.monaco-workbench .part.titlebar > .window-appicon:not(.codicon) {
  background-image: url(ICON-URL-HERE);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
}
```

VSCode will probably pop a notification saying that your vscode app is corrupted or something like that, just ignore it.